# How to listen to several Firebase Realtime Database nodes at the same time and in real time?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app that each user can participate in several chat groups. When opening each chat I write in the database that the message was read by the user. Now I need to know in real time if any of the groups I participate in have unread messages and put the result in a `boolean hasUnreadChats`. How can I listen to all chats at the same time and find out if there are any with unread messages?

database:

```
{
"myGroups" : {
    "userA" : {
      "-GROUPABC" : true,
      "-GROUPCDE" : true,
      "-GROUPFGH" : true
    },
    "userB" : {
      "-GROUPABC" : true
    }
  },
  "readMessagensGroups" : {
    "-GROUPABC" : {
      "-MSG1" : {
        "userA" : true,
        "userB" : true
      },
      "-MSG2" : {
        "userA" : true
      }
    },
    "-GROUPCDE" : {
        "-MSG1" : {
          "userA" : true,
          "userB" : true
        },
        "-MSG2" : {
          "userA" : true
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the parent node and there traverse the children, once that is finished update the UI

```
object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val reads = dataSnapshot.getValue<Map<String, Boolean>>()
        var hasUnread = reads.values().firstOrNull { it.not }  ?: false
        //update ui
    }

    override fun onCancelled...
```

So your `dataSnapshot` is a map where the key is the chat id and the value is if has read or not. In Kotlin maps you can get the values, then find if there is any the complies the condition `is true` in this case simply `it.not` because is a boolean. If any is `false` then you have at least 1 unread.

I'm assuming the correct reference is `myGroups/{uid}/{chatId}`.